# Can't find referenced method google.android.gms.internal.zzelh

Tags: android, json, gradle

I encountered a code error when trying to sign Gradle apk. I don't know how to solve this problem. Please tell me if you know how.

My Gradle app and error message from the Gradle console:

```
dependencies {
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
        transitive = true

    }
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.3'
    //implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
    //implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta4'
    //implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
    //implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    // Firebase Module Comfiguration System Library
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    // End Firebase Module Configuration System Library
    //Membuat Funfgsi Untuk Melakukan Fungsi Tambahan Untuk Module Di dalam system Gradle
    implementation 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.github.halysongoncalves:pugnotification:1.8.1'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    // costum gradle
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.6.0'
    //implementation files('libs/mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin.jar')
    // Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    //implementation 'com.akexorcist:googledirectionlibrary:1.1.1'


}
```

After I try to build signed apk, an error like this appears:

```
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelh: can't find referenced method 'org.json.JSONStringer array()' in program class org.json.JSONStringer
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelh: can't find referenced method 'org.json.JSONStringer endArray()' in program class org.json.JSONStringer
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelh: can't find referenced method 'org.json.JSONStringer endObject()' in program class org.json.JSONStringer
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelh: can't find referenced method 'org.json.JSONStringer key(java.lang.String)' in program class org.json.JSONStringer
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelh: can't find referenced method 'org.json.JSONStringer object()' in program class org.json.JSONStringer
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelh: can't find referenced method 'org.json.JSONStringer value(java.lang.Object)' in program class org.json.JSONStringer
Warning:there were 6 unresolved references to program class members.
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

And This is My Proguard :

```
# Uncomment this to preserve the line number information for
# debugging stack traces.
#-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# If you keep the line number information, uncomment this to
# hide the original source file name.
#-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
 -dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
#### -- Picasso --
 -dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**
```

Comment: you should probably update your proguard rules if it's enabled (I guess it is). almost every library provide it's own proguard rules so you should check them and see if that helps : ) if not, than update your question with your proguard settings and with more info.

Comment: I have done a set on my proguard like this:

#-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
 -dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
#### -- Picasso --
 -dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**
 -dontwarn com.google.android.gms.internal.zzhu